# how to save video in database sql server using xamarin android web service and display in listview

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, web-services, xamarin.android

how to save video in database sql server using xamarin android  web service and display in listview

Comment: What did you tried so far?

Comment: Is there a possibility or not

Comment: Sure it is, any data is just a bunch of bytes and that can be stored by any SQL server (binary column)

Comment: thanks for your information.. Can you help me with an example for web services with xamarin android

Comment: Sorry, but this site is not a code writing service

Comment: There should be a lot of examples how to build a webservice, how to read/write data to SQL server, how to consume a webservice from Xamarin Android app and how to display data in a listview. Look out for each of them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would strongly advise not to store videos in your database due to the following reasons:

```
1). Doing so would bloat your database size
2). Slow down the performance of the database
3). It opens your application to Denial of Service attacks (DDOS).
```

You should look forward to storing your videos on a file dedicated storage like:

```
1). Cloud Storage.
2). FTP storage.
3). Server's file system.
4). Etc...
```

If you really want to store videos on your database for testing or bench marking purposes, you can try the following code:

```
 using System;
 using System.Data;
 using System.Data.SqlClient;

 namespace Portal.WebApp.Models
 {
     public class DbBlobSaver
     {
         #region Public Methods
         public void Execute(byte[] fileBytes)
         {
             using (var dbConnection = new SqlConnection("Data Source = .; Initial Catalog = BlobsDatabase; Integrated Security = SSPI"))
             {
                 var command = BuildCommand(dbConnection);
                 var blobParameter = BuildParameter(fileBytes);

                 command.Parameters.Add(blobParameter);

                 try
                 {
                     command.Connection.Open();
                     command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                 }
                 catch (Exception ex)
                 {
                     // Log errors here
                 }
                 finally
                 {
                     command.Connection.Close();
                 }
             }
         }
         #endregion

         #region Private Methods
         private SqlParameter BuildParameter(byte[] fileBytes)
         {
             var blobParameter = new SqlParameter("@BlobFile", SqlDbType.Binary);

             blobParameter.Value = fileBytes;

             return blobParameter;
         }

         private SqlCommand BuildCommand(SqlConnection connection)
         {
             var command = new SqlCommand();
             command.Connection = connection;
             command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
             command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO BlobsTable(BlobFile)" + "VALUES (@BlobFile)";

             return command;
         }
         #endregion
     }
 }
```

Comment: @AhmedRashed giving the answer an upvote would definitely help the community! Thanks also :)

Comment: Saving the file as a file also improves the cachability.